# Benefit of 'Delay Thread creation until needed' option in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can anyone please tell me the benefits of "Delay Thread creation until needed" option in Jmeter - Thread Group? I know the use of this option. However, I would like to know how can this option impact the performance test?

Comment: explain what have you tried so far

Comment: Hi Nargis, I know the practical use of 'Delay Thread creation until needed' option. I just want to know the benefit of this option. Kindly assist

Answer (score 9):

Here's a useful link:
http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Delayed-thread-creation-was-OnDemand-ThreadGroup-td5714355.html

Focus when he says:
"When this is selected, the threads in a thread group are only created
and started when they are due to run.
The startup delay (if any) and ramp-up delay are now performed before
the thread data is created.

This means that the memory requirements are proportional to the number
of concurrent active threads, rather than the total thread count.
Provided that the active count does not grow too large, it should be
possible to run tests with very large maximum thread count.

If "Delayed thread creation" is not selected, JMeter behaves as
before, i.e. all thread resouces are created at the start of a test. "

Hope it helps!